# Ca(OH)2 not dissolving even as much as it should

Tags: acid-base

according to solubility charts Ca(OH)2 should dissolve at 20-25 oC at about 1.6g per litre.  I have tried 0.8, 0.4 and 0.2g in 500ml and even the 0.2 does not completely dissolve, even left overnight. (in fact I would say most of it is undissolved on the bottom of the flask).  rm temp is around 19-20oC, using lab grade ca(OH)2 and distilled water Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Could part of it be already CaCO3 ? How does the not dissolved part behave in an acid? Another alternative is Ca(OH)2 can be covered by CaCO3 that kinetically slows down the dissolution.

Comment: Well, you should heat it and mix instead of wasting time - some things won't just do by itself.

Comment: Check for calcium carbonate with a little vinegar reation. The water may also contain dissolved calcium salts or CO2 whhich converts the hydroxide to the carbonate.